# Android picasso scale photos to be bigger or fit the imageView (no white space)

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso, android-bitmap

I have a serious problem with the Picasso library scaling. The problem is that I have a layout consisting of 3 Main views and some buttons. Views are like :

ImageView 50%
mapView 20%
EditTextView 30%

And I want to load pictures of unknown resolution into that imageView without leaving white spaces. I was trying to use .fit().centerInside but that just left white spaces on the sides. This is how my layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photo1"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#75aea7ab" />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_shape"
    android:src="@drawable/forward"
    android:text="Post!"
    android:tint="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/camera" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gallery" />
```

Comment: So you have a fixed size `ImageView` but variably sized images - and you want to fill the whole ImageView. In that case `fit().centerCrop()` seems the way to go. Of course, it will crop your images, but if the aspect ratio of the images does not fit that of the `ImageView` you only have the two choice: (1) fit - with white bars or (2) crop - with some parts of the image lost.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I was afraid of this response. So any other way to achieve this without cropping ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Do you want to stretch the image to fit the ImageView? Or do you want to resize the ImageView to fit the image, even if that breaks/changes your whole layout. As for the latter, see https://disqus.com/home/discussion/jpardogo/resize_and_respect including my comments to the blog post. The former is probably possible with a `Transformation`, but I'd have to try and/or google that myself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you try to set the ***ScaleType*** after the image has been loaded?

```
   mPicasso.load("yourUrl")
                    .into(yourImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);//Or ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //nothing for now
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hey, thats's a good idea, my problem is that I am loading into a target to extract the bitmap from imageview

Comment: I put it into a target and it works veeery good. thanks man :)

Comment: Wait, how is that different than `fit().centerCrop()` or `fit().centerInside()`, respectively?

Comment: First Picasso's fit() would scale down the image and center the image view but will perform no scaling then centerCrop will Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding) but you still need to (in Picasso's case) give a width and height for this new bitmap, fit().centerInside() will do the same but  when centerInside is called it should Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio).

Comment: That's a good question but fit().centerCrop() or fit().centerInside() don't work for me but this works. And also, I can't use those methods because I have to put it into Target not directly to ImageView because I want to get the reference of the bitmap